# Is it possible to preserve a particular version of a page for a certain amount of time in AEM?

Tags: aem

We need to preserve a particular version of the pages for a certain amount of time, lets say for an year.

If we use the Version Manager and provide the '`Max Version Age`' and '`Max Number Versions`', it will preserve the latest x number of versions for that amount of time.

Is there a way to differentiate in the versions and preserve a particular one(NOT the latest one) for x number of days?

Or Is there any other criteria to preserve the versions other than the latest ones?

Answer (score 0):

you'd just need to set max number of versions to a number below 1.

Please be cautious about the potential repository growth this represents (basically N pages times the number of times a page gets versioned in a year).

Answer (score 0):

The version manager doesn't provide the granularity to preserve a specific page version beyond a certain date and/or number of versions other than disabling version management altogether. If you have a particular version of a page or site that you wish to keep beyond the scope of the version manager, you can always create a package of this content that can either be stored in the package manager or downloaded to external storage.